# How to load a JPG image into a TImage component

Tags: image, delphi

I added the file sant.jpg into the code file and tried to run the code to load the image

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  IMG.Picture.LoadFromFile('sant.JPG');
end;
```

tried but got
unknown picture file extension (.JPG)

Comment: I already tried adding the .jepg to the uses it did not work

Answer (score 5):

Adding the `Jpeg` unit into the uses clause should fix this problem.

For example:

```
uses
  Windows, Messages, ..., Jpeg;
```

Comment: In XE2 and later, use the unit scope name `Vcl.Imaging.Jpeg` instead, unless you add the unit scope `Vcl.Imaging` to your project settings.